# Find cell address in another workbook with its value: "Run time error '9' Subscript out of range"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working with a user form that contains a listBox and I'm trying to look for the list items in another workbook to get their cell addresses if found.

My code is as follow:

```
With Me.listbox
   For i=0 To listbox.ListCount -1
       colNum = WorksheetFunction.Match(listbox.List(i), Workbooks("c:\sourceFile").Worksheets(1).Range("1:1"), 0)
       MsgBox "Column :" & colNum

   Next i
End With
```

An error message pops up telling me "Run time error '9' Subscript out of range".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see the following problems you might be facing:

1) use Application.Match instead of WorksheetFunction, the latter is not a member of the UserForm Object

2) I doubt that the name of the listBox member is not listbox, most probably ListBox1 or so

3)

> Workbooks("c:\sourceFile")

.. does that reference an open workbook? if so, you should get it by using its name (with extension) but without the path.

```
With Me.ListBox1
   For i=0 To .ListCount -1
       colNum = Application.Match(.List(i), Workbooks("sourceFile.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Range("1:1"), 0)
       MsgBox "Column :" & colNum
   Next i
End With
```

Finally, your code can be better optimized by getting the range to search once for all, not inside the loop:

```
set r = Workbooks("sourceFile.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Range("1:1")
With Me.ListBox1
   For i=0 To .ListCount -1
       colNum = Application.Match(.List(i), r, 0)
       MsgBox "Column :" & colNum
   Next i
End With
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the problem was in the range because I was working with the full path of the source file.